# How are you supposed to know which parameters you can pass into a class?

Tags: python, folium

Lately I've been following a tutorial and I need to recreate a project. In this instance it's a map made with openstreetmap and folium. On the example map i'm to recreate is a map with small circle markers that are all of a different color.

The first thing I do is open jupyter notebook python session and enter this:

```
>>> import folium
>>> dir(folium)
```

from here I see all the things that I can do with folium. One of them is called "Circle.Marker" and seems to be exactly what I need.

```
>>> help(folium.CircleMarker)
```

and I'm greeted with this:

"Help on class `CircleMarker` in module `folium.vector_layers`:

```
class CircleMarker(folium.map.Marker)

CircleMarker(location=None, radius=10, popup=None, tooltip=None, **kwargs)"
```

I see that the parameters that I can pass into CircleMarker are location, radios, popup, tootip, and **kwargs)

unfortunately none of them seem to be what I need. Then I go to the code example and see that they've passed

```
folium.CircleMarker(location= foo, popup = foo , radius = foo, fill_color = foo)
```

How was i ever supposed to know that "fill_color" was a parameter that circlemarker would accept? I looked at the "**kwargs" part and that also doesn't seem to be the answer. This must mean that I'm missing some fundamental step in the learning process.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker

Comment: If you don't read/study the documentation your progress will be impeded. Sometimes it is helpful to read the source code.

Comment: (You'll also learn that documentation often sucks. Here, the existence of `fill_color` is sort of documented, in that it's listed in the `path_options` docs, which are linked from the `CircleMarker` docs, but the docs don't make it clear that `fill_color` is a valid keyword argument for `CircleMarker`, and if you look at the end of the `path_options` docs, you'll see a bunch of garbage due to broken markup.)

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little familiar with documentation from working with other libraries. It has seemed like a less efficient way to express the help() material. I see now that there's  a difference between them and that I should read it more carefully. Thank you to user2357112, Klaus D, and Wii. After reading the documentation carefully, I do see that there's a final part of the "folium.vector_layers" documentation called "path_options" which says that it "contains options and constants shared between vector overlays". So, all of them here can pass these. Thanks again!